# How to test if state of a component is changed by the function using jest and Enzyme in React TDD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function which is used to change the state of the component to empty arrays. I want to test this function. My function looks like this:

```
clearAppliedFilters = () => {
  this.setState({
    appliedFilterList: {
      access: [],
      bandwidth: [],
      term: [],
    },
  });
};
```

I am writing a test case as shown below for this function:

```
it('checks clearAppliedFilters function', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <ProductList
      headerText="Hello World"
      productList={data}
      paginationSize="10"
      accessFilters={['a 1', 'a 2']}
      bandwidthFilters={['b 1', 'b 2']}
      termsFilters={['t 1', 't 2']}
      appliedFilterList={appliedFilter}
    />,
  );
  wrapper.setState({
    appliedFilterList: {
      access: [],
      bandwidth: [],
      term: [],
    },
  });

  expect(wrapper.instance().clearAppliedFilters()).toBe();
});
```

But I am not able to see my test running. So what may be the issue? Can anyone please help me if I this looks wrong. I am new to TDD and I am struggling to write these tests. Can someone please suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working test case, this might help you further:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xr9295ov3q

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";

    describe("ProductList Components", () => {
      it("should update correct ProductList state", () => {
        let wrapper = shallow(<ProductList />);

        wrapper.instance().clearAppliedFilters();

        expect(wrapper.state().appliedFilterList.access.length).toBe(0);
        expect(wrapper.state().appliedFilterList.bandwidth.length).toBe(0);
        expect(wrapper.state().appliedFilterList.term.length).toBe(0);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am not able to see the test file in the sandbox editor.Sorry, I might be doing wrong while checking.But if you don't mind, could you please put the testing code here so that I can view the code.

Comment: Added! But you can see the ProductList.spec.js file on the left-hand side.

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot,its working.I am not getting any error.But 1 doubt i have.How do we know that the specific test has passed successfully? Is there a way to find out if all the tests in a test file are run or not or we can understand that by only seeing that the test suite has passed overall meaning all of them have passed? Sorry, it might sound a very silly question,but I want to check if all the tests are passed individually. Anyway thanks a lot for the help. :)